# Can a game made with pygame be submitted to Steam?

Tags: python, distribution, pygame, steam

After making games with XNA, I wanted to broaden my horizon by working with python. I know XNA is supposedly easy to distribute; however, i'm not sure if a game made with pygame compiled with py2exe could be submitted to steam? My overall question is...How would I submit a game made with pygame to steam?

Comment: If you want to broaden your horizon, stay __clear__ from pygame. Use pyglet + pyOpenGL.

Comment: @nightcracker Why `+`? I don't think the two work particularly well together, and pyglet allows raw OpenGL too.

Comment: @delnan: from http://www.pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/the_opengl_interface.html: _"The interface is provided by the pyglet.gl package. To use it you will need a good knowledge of OpenGL, C and ctypes. You may prefer to use OpenGL without using ctypes, in which case you should investigate PyOpenGL. PyOpenGL provides similar functionality with a more "Pythonic" interface, and will work with pyglet without any modification."_

Comment: @nightcracker Ah right, now I remember.

Comment: @nightcracker what's wrong with pygame

Comment: @jawerty: the documentation is horrific. The examples and code written with it are ranging from less-than-stellar to horrific. The performance is downright awful.

Comment: @nightcracker I get what you mean, I've been working with pygame today and I'm already finding trouble finding the answers to some of my basic pygame syntax problems.

Comment: I've asked the game dev SE site if this question would be more suitable with them.

Comment: @jawerty While I didn't have the most complicated thing, I still had a good time with PyGame. The docs are terrible, but it teaches you to look around online for answers. The performance might not be all that great down the road though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That it is Python, assembly or XNA doesn't really matter for Steam, AFAIK. There are two general ways to distribute games through Steam, contacting the Steam team (I just love saying that) themselves, or getting accepted through the [Green Light](http://steamcommunity.com/greenlight/) program.

Seeing that you aren't a AAA game dev team, the latter would probably be the best option.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the process was much different. I will consider the Green Light program